# how to dynamically change array of object size in java

Tags: java

I need to create dynamically changing array of object. how to create this. pls help me.

```
PrefixMatcher[] pm = new PrefixMatcher[8];
Scanner infile = new Scanner(new File(url.toURI()));
while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
      int len = infline.length();
      //here i need to create reinitialize the same object using length of the file's first line      

}
```

Comment: Any reason you cannot use an ArrayList?

Comment: i have to get the details of particular object using object only i.e pm[124] like this. in pm[124] object i stored unique value. but in ArrayList we need to search every item.

Comment: `pm.get(124);` would do it if `pm` was an ArrayList. More: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Comment: @user3300015: What???

Comment: @user3300015 you can access the value stored in arraylist at particular location by using `get`. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are of fixed size that is specified when they are declared. To increase the size of the array you have to create a new array with a larger size and copy all of the old values into the new array.

ex:

```
char[] copyFrom  = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' };
char[] copyTo    = new char[7];

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copyFrom));
System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 0, copyTo, 0, copyFrom.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copyTo));
```

another example:

```
 String[] array = new String[5];
 ...
 array = expand(array, 10);

 private String[] expand(String[] array, int size) {
   String[] temp = new String[size];
   System.arraycopy(array, 0, temp, 0, array.length);
   for(int j = array.length; j < size; j++)
      temp[j] = "";
   return temp;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give you a +1 for making the attempt to at least answer the OP's question as it's asked...I'd like a mention of `List`/Collections, but seen as we can't clarify why the OP can/can't use these, this is the closes to actually giving them an answer...

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` is what you are looking for, an implementation of `List` which uses array internally to store data

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ArrayList`. ArrayList can be used when size of array is not fixed.

```
ArrayList<PrefixMatcher> pm = new ArrayList<PrefixMatcher>();
```

You can access the elements at particular location by giving index.

```
pm.get(123);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize an array, I think that much is obvious by now, but, if you can't use of the of `List` implementations of the [Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/), you can create a new array, that is larger than the first, and copy it's contents to it, then replace the reference.

```
String[] values = new String[10];
String[] newValues = new String[20];
System.arraycopy(values, 0, newValues, 0, values.length);
values = newValues;
```

You could wrap this in a method to make it easier...

```
public String[] grow(String[] source, int newSize) {
    String[] newValues = new String[20];
    System.arraycopy(source, 0, newValues, 0, source.length);
    return newValues;
}
```

Personally, though...I'd seriously consider using something like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`...it's just simpler ;)